# Email tracking in mail merge MS Word

Tags: c#, mailmerge

Online marketing portals such as SendGrid, Google, add an invisible pixel to email which when rendered by the server, the user opens the email is tracked.

I would like the same in MS Word-based email campaigns.

We have a web service that returns an image after accepting a token as a parameter.

The problem we are facing is that when we add the image URL in the Word template, the image API is called immediately. The image API should be called in Outlook/ other email clients only when a user opens the email.

How can this be accomplished?

Any advice here will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Assign each sent e-mail an unique hash. Pass that hash to the "image", if no (valid) hash is present then don't track?

Comment: Sorry...but i can not make any sense of this....can you please explain again?